# Prefixos usando Css Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

Olá, 
Estou começando a usar o css `Stylus` e estou com problemas para adicionar os prefixos dos browsers. Existe algum autoprefixer que adiciona tudo automaticamente ou tenho que fazer tudo manual?

Obrigado.

Obs : *tentei usar este https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer-stylus , mas ocorreu um erro na instalação via npm* (`npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240`)

Comment: `+1` por estares a usar o Stylus :) Como está o teu código de configuração? Qual foi o erro que deu?

Comment: Obrigado =D   ,  
Então , quando tento instalar o Autoprefixer via npm , ele me retorna um erro de `Windows_NT`

Comment: Podes colocar o erro na pergunta? qual a versão do Stylus e do NodeJS que estás a usar?

Comment: @Sergio coloquei o erro na pergunta;  
A versão do node que uso é 4.2.1 ; 
E a do Stylus é 0.52.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma biblioteca para os prefixos , chama-se `nib` , eu já tinha visto mas não sabia como usa-la. Descobri que é preciso usar o `@import` e importar a pasta `nib`.
O outro erro que relatei sobre o npm , eu consegui solucionar atualizando o node.js

Obrigado a todos! =)

Comment: A biblioteca Nib é bem útil mesmo e se convenciona usar ela sempre.
Além da possibilidade de incluí-la ela através do ```@import```, é possível adicionar ela na tarefa do Gulp para compilação do CSS, e daí colocar elas como uma dependência do projeto.